# Static reference of a class object

Tags: php, class, oop, reference, static

I have written several classes that all need to be instantiated when used.

My goal was to be able to have the perfect organization when trying to create dynamic access between instantiated classes.

In one class it would have several methods it calls based on what it just did. Inside one of these methods would be methods from other classes. (Currently static methods) I would edit these lines to control the behavior between classes.

What i mean by being dynamic is, if one of the static methods is not available or will be available later, then it simply executes a different method to complete the task internally.

My question
is a matter of concern of proper OOP. I am not sure if there is a better way or if what im doing can cause problems. Although, it works pretty well.

I have an example prepared below. Of which, is a representation, not actual situation.
executingFileOne is one situation and ExecutingFileTwo is another.

executingFileOne.php

```
require_once 'login.php';
$login = new Login();

require_once 'serverData.php';
$servDat = new serverData();

//blah blah blah
```

executingFileTwo.php

```
require_once 'serverData.php';
$servDat = new serverData();

//blah blah blah
```

login.php

```
class Login {

    private static $thisClass = null;

    public function __construct(){
        //Get and set user data.
        self::setStaticClass($this);
    }

    public static function setStaticClass(&$inputClass){
        self::$thisClass = $inputClass;
    }

    //Methods Methods Methods

    //---Methods Executed by class at specific times---------------
    // - - - Used to get input from other classes

    //Methods Methods Methods

    //-------------------------------------------------------------

    //---Methods for other classes.--------------------------------
    // - - - Used to output data to other classes
    public static function getUserID(){
        die('Test'.self::$thisClass->userID);
    }

    //Methods Methods Methods of other classes.

    //-------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

serverData.php

```
class serverData {

    private static $thisClass = null;

    public function __construct(){
        //work work work
        //an IF statement detected needing to register userID on serverData
            $this->registerOnServer();
        //work work work
        self::setStaticClass($this);
    }

    //Methods Methods Methods

    public function registerOnServer(){
        //work work work
        $this->userID = $this->getUserID();
        //add userID to registration data.
    }

    //---Methods Executed by class at specific times---------------
    // - - - Used to get input from other classes
    private function getUserID(){
        if (class_exists('Login')) {
            return Login::getUserID();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------

    //---Methods for other classes.--------------------------------
    // - - - Used to output data to other classes

    //Methods Methods Methods of other classes.

    //-------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Comment: I am not familiar with that alternative.

Comment: I looked that up, but one of my problems is that on specific situations one class is not called all the time. In order for that to work I would have to edit hundreds of pages to get that working. And if i changed it, it would require me to edit those hundred files... I think.

Take for example the Login class is required by the serverData class, but, the Login class is not always available.

Comment: Ahh, fixing old code can be .. a challenge. This is why I start all new projects with DI/IoC from the start. Anyway, a good IoC container will also support *optional dependencies*, or alternatively a *mock dependency* can be used (it fulfills a DI requirement, but doesn't actually "do" anything if it is used) - the important thing is that the same interface is provided (and that the service operates as expected in context).

Comment: can you provide an example of what you describe. I'm having difficulty understanding this design pattern.

Comment: I have clarified further to represent how they are called. Also, I am still not able to make the connection here. This design pattern is waaay out of context for me. I was hoping giving an example made out of the example code I made would help show me exactly what your talking about.

Comment: You cannot use `$this` to access a `static function`, you can however set `static` variables within a `function` that is not `static`.

Comment: @PHPglue the syntax is not in question here.

Comment: @user2864740 So your saying, pass in $Login (and/or check against a possible null)?

Comment: I guess i need to add something,>> The area of which I put in the methods to call other classes could contain more that 4 other classes. For the sake of making one action will trigger other actions across other classes.

Comment: So if serverData class will interact with 6 other class, i would pass them in as well. When i see something like that, it makes me wonder if there is a better dynamic way to do this. Which is my goal. I'm just worried that this is a bad way to go.

Comment: Look into `spl_autoload_register()` and `autoload()`. `__autoload()` may become depreciated. http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php  http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php

Comment: @TrinaryAtom If your serverData class has to interact with 6 other classes, you will need some way to pass them in no matter what. If you are trying to avoid methods/constructors with long arguments list, then perhaps consider extracting a common interface from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the several issues when using static classes, and it is compounded due to the sneaky self-registration and strong coupling at the usage-site. Currently the "best" solution I know of to this problem in general, and one which I encourage, to this issue is to use Dependency Injection.

Further, using an IoC (Inversion of Control) container on top of DI can making wiring everything together and managing lifetimes a sane process. (Do *not* revert to a Service Locator pattern except in very specific cases or the beautiy of DI+IoC is lost!)

While an informal duck-typed "interface" is sufficient, using codified interfaces helps with classification - and are often (but not always) required for IoC containers to be able to register and resolve components.

```
// This is the service (interface) that different components will provider
inteface ILogin {
   public function getUserID ();
}

// Primary component (implementation) for the login service (interface)
class Login implements ILogin {
   // Note:
   // Constructor does NOT "register itself statically"; even when using
   // an approach similar to the original, use a proper Singleton Design.

   public function getUserID () { /* .. */ }
}

// Alternative/mock component (implementation) for the login service (interface)
class NoLogin implements ILogin {
   public function getUserID () { return 0; }
}

// Class (possibly also a component) that uses the login service dependency
class ServerData {
    // Constructor-based DI; the components are supplied as arguments
    // (There is also property-based DI.)
    public function __constructor(ILogin $login) {
        $this->login = $login;
    }

    // Later on we use the service
    // (It is a bit silly just to proxy the service, which should be
    //  injected elsewhere as required, but this mirrors the original.)
    public function getUserID () {
        // If not using a "mock service", then guard $this->login for null
        // because it is now an optional dependency; the appropriate approach
        // will vary based upon specific use-case.
        return $this->login->getUserID();
    }
}
```

Then later on:

```
// File 1-
// Note how dependency is "injected" into the server data
$servDat = new ServerData(new Login());

// File 2-
// A different dependency providing the same contract/service is used
$servDat = new ServerData(new NoLogin());
// Or, if ServerData guards usage and the service is "optional"
// $servDat = new ServerData(null);
```

So that is one form of DI (although general term is IoC, of which DI is an implementation) at the core - simple, but not very exciting and it can get tedious. Also, even though dependencies have been moved "outside" the immediate usage-site, they are still effectively hard-code at the consumer creating the instance and manually injecting the components.

Now, where does the magic with DI+IoC fit in? Components are registered into an IoC container and the IoC container is used to instantiate the objects - such a container is smart enough to *automatically resolve* DI dependencies. Then the only difference between File#1 and File#2 is that they use a slightly different IoC configuration (one uses Login and the other NoLogin for the ILogin service).

Other useful feature of IoC is the ability to configure object lifetimes. In this case the Login component (fulfilling the login service) might be instance-per-request which is effectively "singleton behavior" - except that it can't leak between requests *and* the Login component is now loosely-coupled with the ServerData class.

There is *a lot* more to an IoC container - see [PHP DI](http://php-di.org/) which seems to have a fairly good introduction. Note that the *same* DI-ready code presented above could be used (in PHP-DI) for the component resolution to occur. (Bugs are free.)

Comment: You have 21K reputation and you don't even bother typing a nick-name?

Comment: @bad_boy Maybe I typed in "user2864740" :D (But in reality, I've grown rather fond of the number - like a first license plate.)

Comment: Well, it's not that nice, anyways... If you only typed a nickname, then you would look better. This is because we all see crappy questions and answers from users with random numbers with 1 rep or so

Comment: interesting things about annotations: https://r.je/php-annotations-are-an-abomination.html

Comment: @bad_boy It is a good read, and there is definitely something to be said about such usage - although most of the arguments don't apply to DI itself (PHP-DI can use type-hinting, if that is considered any better by the author, I don't know). But I'm really a C# guy so I look at most of those arguments and go "pfft" - but I'm biased by my statically-typed experience, a lot.

Comment: A little bit confusing for me, but i understand. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine showed me an option that is a better approach than mine. Probably not the right solution, but better.

Seeing as i instantiate my classes and can simply access the within other classes by calling the variable, globally. Instead of creating anything static.

For example:

```
require_once 'login.php';
$login = new Login();

require_once 'serverData.php';
$servDat = new serverData();

//blah blah blah


class Login {

    public function __construct(){
        //Get and set user data.
    }

    //Methods Methods Methods

    //---Methods Executed by class at specific times---------------
    // - - - Used to get input from other classes

    //Methods Methods Methods

    //-------------------------------------------------------------

    //---Methods for other classes.--------------------------------
    // - - - Used to output data to other classes
    public static function getUserID(){
        die('Test'.$this->userID);
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------
}

class serverData {

    public function __construct(){
        //work work work
        //an IF statement detected needing to register userID on serverData
            $this->registerOnServer();
        //work work work
    }

    //Methods Methods Methods

    public function registerOnServer(){
        //work work work
        $this->userID = $this->getUserID();
        //add userID to registration data.
    }

    //---Methods Executed by class at specific times---------------
    // - - - Used to get input from other classes
    private function getUserID(){
        global $login;
        if ($login != null) {
            return $login->getUserID();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------

    //---Methods for other classes.--------------------------------
    // - - - Used to output data to other classes

    //Methods Methods Methods

    //-------------------------------------------------------------
}
```